# Mac Catalyst replacement for iOS panGestureRecognizer.location

Tags: ios, swift, uipangesturerecognizer, mac-catalyst

I currently have an iOS app that I'm converting to Mac Catalyst, MacOs Big Sur 11.2.1, Swift 5 Xcode 12.4 (12D4e). I have a scrollView, on it I have added various other views of random sizes. Currently, in iOS, I can touch one of the subviews and by getting the the location of the touch I can find with view was selected. Now, in Mac, I click on the same subview, but PanGestureRecognizer.location doesn't return a correct CGPoint, like in iOS. Not sure if this is a bug with Xcode or I'm missing something else in the conversion to MacCatalyst.

I've searched the web, for possible replacements, but I haven't found any good replacements.

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class GraphController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var xxScrollView: UIScrollView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    
    super.viewDidLoad(

    let scrollViewTap   = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(touchFromScrollView))

    xxScrollView.addGestureRecognizer(scrollViewTap)
    
    xxScrollView.delegate = self
}

@objc func touchFromScrollView() {
    
    let location: CGPoint = xxScrollView.panGestureRecognizer.location(in: xxScrollView)

    testTouches(location)
}

func testTouches(_ location: CGPoint?) {
    // code to look up "location" in table
}
```

Corrected Solution

```
@objc func touchFromScrollView(gesture:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    
//      let location: CGPoint = cdScrollView.panGestureRecognizer.location(in: cdScrollView)
    
    let location: CGPoint = gesture.location(in: cdScrollView)
    
    testTouches(location)
}
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are not using the location from the tap gesture ?

Comment: Thanks Warren, much better solution.